# Problema al llamar a función (o su resultado) dentro de otra

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, function

Tengo un problema al llamar a una funcion anterior dentro de una nueva.
Imaginad que tengo una funcion con esta cabecera `FUNCTION` ejer2`(n_resultado varchar(7))`
y esa funcion me va a dar solo dos resultados: O un 1 o por el contrario un 0.

Entonces ahora tengo esta codigo, que es otra función y no se como llamar a la primera(ejer2):

```
declare salida int(3);


select count(resultado)
    from partido23
        where locall = 'mad' and ejer2(n_resultado) = 0 
            or visitante = 'mad' and ejer2(n_resultado) = 1 into salida;
```

Tengo que conseguir que esa consulta me saque el numero de veces en las que el equipo 'mad' ya sea locall o visitante haya dado como resultado un 1 o un 0 en la funcion anterior.
El error que me sale, es que no reconoce la variable n_resultado in where clause, pero está bien escrita y en la primera función no da errores
Muchas Gracias

Comment: Claro ¿n_resultado de donde lo sacas cuando llamas a ejer2 en el SELECT?  A no ser que te refieres a la columna resultado de la tabla

Comment: Nota la diferencia entre el valor y el nombre de un parámetro; prueba con: `… = 'mad' and ejer2(resultado) = …`

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich n_resultado es un parametro, puedo meter el valor al llamar a la función

Comment: Así como está la función  no se aprecia la definición de n_resultado.